# Get confidence of net in theanets

Tags: neural-networks, theano

In theanets, how can I get the net's "confidence" that it is correct? Specifically, I have two output neurons, for two classes, how can I get their values when I predict on an input?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `net.predict_proba(X)` if your `net` is a `theanets.Classifier` model. This will return the probabilities of the output classes for each input in `X`.

API documentation lives at http://theanets.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/theanets.feedforward.Classifier.html#theanets.feedforward.Classifier.predict_proba